# Asio read_until multiple end tags

Tags: boost-asio

I have a little client-server application written in asio standalone. It works just fine though I realized there is problem with accepting different messages from different clients.

For example one part of system (let's call it Server A) replies in xml messages, therefore I can specify  as an end tag and happily go with read_until.

Problem occurs when another part of system (let's call it Server B) replies in json and i don't want to use  as delimiter.

What is the solution to having more connections with different delimiters on one socket? Documentation is vague and I am unable to find example how to do it.

Comment: Asio's documentation will not go into detail about how to handle application protocols.  If you have control over the application protocol, then consider passing some auxiliary information, such as a header indicating body type and preferable length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the first half dozen or so characters and decide whether it is xml or json.  You can probable determing from just the first non-white character: < for xml or { for json.  Then read the rest with the appropriate delimiter